# switch to RESTAdapter - EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I have been looking at EmberJS tutorials, but all of them use FixtureAdapter, and I'm trying to switch to RESTAdapter, but I'm facing a persistent error

```
Error: Assertion Failed: Expected an object as `data` in a call to push for Books.Book , but was undefined
```

here's the code for the adapter:

```
Books.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
host: 'http://localhost:24818/api/'});
```

and calling the api in the router:

```
Books.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
return this.store.find('book',1);
 } 
});
```

How do I get store.find to return a JSON to be used in the Handlebars template?

Many thanks,

Edit: this is my API response:

```
[{"Id":1,"Title":"Pride and Prejudice","Year":1813,"Price":9.99,"Genre":"Comedy of manners","AuthorId":1,"Author":null},{"Id":2,"Title":"Northanger Abbey","Year":1817,"Price":12.95,"Genre":"Gothic parody","AuthorId":1,"Author":null},{"Id":3,"Title":"David Copperfield","Year":1850,"Price":15.00,"Genre":"Bildungsroman","AuthorId":2,"Author":null},{"Id":4,"Title":"Don Quixote","Year":1617,"Price":8.95,"Genre":"Picaresque","AuthorId":3,"Author":null}]
```

Edit: add model definition:

```
Books.Book = DS.Model.extend({
title: DS.attr('string'),
year: DS.attr('number'),
price: DS.attr('number'),
genre: DS.attr('string'),
authorId: DS.attr('number'),
author: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: Is your api working?

Comment: yes, it's returning (200 OK) and in the inspector it displays the JSON response, but when I try to assign store.find to a variable, it's an empty object

Comment: Please show your model definition and JSON response from your API.

Comment: What about Model definition?

Comment: added the model definition

Comment: Why do you have dot in your model name?  It isn't normal.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to normalize your response. i.e

```
"books": [
    {
       "id":1,
       "Title":"Pride and Prejudice",
       "Year":1813,
       "Price":9.99,
       "Genre":"Comedy of manners",
       "AuthorId":1,"Author":null
    },
    {
       "id":2,
       "Title":"Northanger Abbey",
       "Year":1817,
       "Price":12.95,
       "Genre":"Gothic parody",
       "AuthorId":1,
       "Author":null
    },
    {
       "id":3,
       "Title":"David Copperfield",
       "Year":1850,
       "Price":15.00,
       "Genre":"Bildungsroman",
       "AuthorId":2,
       "Author":null
    },
]
```

If you have no control over the endpoint. You will need to setup a serializer or normalizer to normalize your response into this expected format.

--

**Useful Links**

[Ember-data Model Maker](http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/)

[Ember JSON Conventions](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_json-conventions)

[REST Serializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html)